# Sending email as a service account gmail api

Tags: python-3.x, google-api, gmail-api, google-api-python-client, service-accounts

To be clear:

- I'm not impersonating another user. I'm sending the email from the service account and the receiver will see the name of the service account as the sender
- I have already enabled gmail api and correctly setup the service account

**Code:**

```py
import base64
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from email.message import EmailMessage
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

creds = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    filename = 'client_secret.json',
    scopes = ['https://mail.google.com/'],
)
service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)
mime_message = EmailMessage()
mime_message['To'] = 'receiving_accont@gmail.com'
mime_message['From'] = 'serviceaccountname@appname.iam.gserviceaccount.com'
mime_message['Subject'] = 'Test Subject'
mime_message.set_content('Test Message')

encoded_message = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(mime_message.as_bytes()).decode()
create_draft_request_body = {
    'message': {'raw': encoded_message}
}
draft = service.users().drafts().create(userId="myuserid",body=create_draft_request_body).execute()
```

Error:

> shell
> <HttpError 400 when requesting https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/myclientid/drafts?alt=json returned "Precondition check failed.". Details: "[{'message': 'Precondition check failed.', 'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'failedPrecondition'}]">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

failedPrecondition means that one of the conditions of using a service account with the gmail api has not been meet.

In order to use a service account with the Gmail api. You **must** configure domain wide [delegation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/delegate_settings) to a user on your google workspace account.

Service accounts by themselves do not have access to send emails. To be 100% clear: What you want to do is not possible. You must configure the subject in the authorization configuration to be that of a user on your workspace domain.  `serviceaccountname@appname.iam.gserviceaccount.com` does not have access to send an email.

```
def _create_client(subject):
    credentials = service_account.Credentials
    credentials = credentials.from_service_account_file('credentials/service_account.json',
        scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.sharing',
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.basic'],
        subject=subject)
    service = discovery.build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=credentials)
    return service
```

What I normally recommend for my clients is to create a dummy `no-reply@yourdomain.com` user and send the emails from that.

Comment: How do i create a dummy `no-reply@yourdomain.com`?
Can you direct me to any tutorials

Comment: Just create a new user on your workspace account.   username no-reply  [Add an account for a new user](https://support.google.com/a/answer/33310?hl=en)   Then just configure domain wide delegation to that user.